# all recursive functions are turing computable

Tags: computability, turing-machines

I'm studying with the book *computability and logic*(boolos).

In chapter 5, the theorem is proved, indirectly, by showing that (recursive => abacus) & (abacus=> turing). But I want to prove (recursive=>turing) without abacus machines but I think this is not easy. So I think I need some nice references for this.

Comment: You can see Martin Davis, [Computability & Unsolvability](https://books.google.it/books?id=TMLgEIOGhBMC&printsec=frontcover) (1958).

Comment: Thanks I checked the related parts